# Stream Song to Device with Multipeer Connectivity - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, multipeer-connectivity

I'm using Multipeer Connectivity to pair two devices and want to stream a song from one device to the other in `Swift`.  I've been following [this walkthrough in Objective-C](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity) closely as well as Apple's documentation, but I admittedly don't have any Obj-C experience.

I'm able to get the track output from AVAssetReaderTrackOutput, add that to an AVAssetReader, and finally start reading.  However, once `CMSampleBufferRef` enters the equation, I start to lose sight of what's actually happening.

If anyone can explain the process of getting samples from the track output and then drilling down to put that data into a stream that MC can consume, that would be much appreciated.